# SQLite error in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a simple piece of code to update a row in `sqlite`:

```
def UpdateElement(new_user,new_topic):
    querycurs.execute('''INSERT into First_Data (topic) values(?) WHERE user = (?)''',([new_topic],    [new_user]))
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Database.py", line 40, in <module>
    UpdateElement("Abhishek Mitra","Particle Physics")
  File "C:/Python27/Database.py", line 36, in UpdateElement
    querycurs.execute('''INSERT into First_Data (topic) values(?) WHERE user = (?)''',([new_topic],[new_user]))
OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using an [UPDATE](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statement instead of INSERT:

```
def UpdateElement(new_user,new_topic):
    querycurs.execute('''UPDATE First_Data 
                         SET topic = ? 
                         WHERE user = ?''', (new_topic, new_user))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the use of the parentheses and sending in new_user as an array, I believe. Values is an array, user is not.

You want something like:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE table SET value=? WHERE name=?", (myvalue, myname))
```

But yes, UPDATE sounds like what you wanted in the first place.